# font awesome icons are behind text field

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

good day, as the title says, my font awesome icons are behind my text field. the icons and text fields are all inside the class="contact" div tag, and the css are all using the contact class as well with added tags. any help would be appreciated thank you.

also, im using bootstrap 4.0.0

[image]

head tag

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My White Card</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/webmain.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/webmain.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
```

HTML/Bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="contact" class="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2 class="med_bg">CONTACT US</h2>
      <p class="mv_font">Thank you for your interest in My White Card and our services. Please fill out the form below about your concern or e-mail us at info@mywhitecard.ph</p>

      <div class="contact col-lg-6 col-md-6">

        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" placeholder="FULL NAME">
        </div>

        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">
        </div>

        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER">
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <textarea name="" id="" cols="80" rows="6" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg med_bg">SUBMIT YOUR MESSAGE</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contact {
  padding: 50px 0 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact p {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  color: #737373;
}

.contact h2 {
  color: #4c4c4c;
  margin: 20px 0 20px;
}

.contact .input-group {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.contact .form-control {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.contact span {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.contact .btn {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #f08300;
  color: #fff;
}

.contact .btn:hover {
  background-color: #f3a64c;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you include your CSS as well.

Comment: HTML alone doesn't show issues, so I assume its in your CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/rjbh6vo2/

Comment: updated the div and css, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I've updated the fiddle with your updated provided code. It still appears we're missing some affected code. I added the font awesome CDN for you, could you include the libraries you're using from your ```head``` tag as well?

Comment: updated to add head tag

Comment: Thanks for including the screenshot. I would have been able to answer a lot faster if I knew it wasn't entirely hidden as I originally thought haha.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like `input-group-addon` contains the font awesome icons, so just set padding on that class.

```
.input-group-addon {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

You may disregard the `font-size` I set if its not good for your use case, I only added this to verify alignment in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjbh6vo2/24/). Give this a try and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: im sorry but it looks like it only made the icon box shrink more. initially the css didnt do anything but once i added !important the box got smaller.

Comment: In that fiddle it's working, and if you had to declare important, there's a conflict somewhere that isn't shown in your question. Post all of your code.